# 3 Diodes-circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

Edited my last question in order to contain the work I've done.

I have to find the output voltage Vo related to the input voltage Vi knowing that the input values range from 0V to 50V. All diodes are ideal.

I started by assuming that D3 is reversed biased. This means that D1 is forward biased and D2 is reversed biased if I am not mistaken.

So, I found VA= 3V (6V/2) using the voltage divider of the 2 5kΩ resistances. I made all this process in order to be able to define the range in which D3 conducts.

So, knowing that VA=3V, when D3 is OFF, I can say that D3 conducts when Ui>3V.

Then I got the range [3V,6V] where D3 and D1 are ON and D2 is OFF and found the output voltage related to the input voltage using the Millman's theorem.

Then I got the range [6V,20V], in which only D3 is ON , so again using a voltage divider on the simplified circuit with the 2,5kΩ and the 5kΩ resistances I found Vo=(2/3)Vi.

Finally I got the range [20V,50V] where both D3 and D2 are ON and D1 is OFF and again using a Millman's theorem found the output voltage.

However I don't know if this is the right way to approach this problem and i am not sure if my process is right. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: A wall of text is very hard to read.  Put your thoughts in paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All diodes are assumed to be ideal.

When Vi > 3V, D3 started conducting.

When it started conducting, Vo = VA will be at \$(Vi + 3)/2\$ volts.

Which means, when Vi = 6V, VA = 4.5V. D1 **does not stop** conducting. It will stop conducting only at VA = 6V, i.e, when Vi = 9V.

After 9V, only D3 will conduct. When it conducts, Vo = VB = \$(2/3)Vi\$ volts.

Which means, Vi should reach 30V, for D2 **to start conducting**. After that both D2, D3 will conduct upto 50V.

Your ranges [3,6] [6,20], [20,50] therefore are incorrect.

You can learn behavior of these circuits by a simulator.

[See here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Av%20288%20368%20288%20272%200%200%2040%206%200%200%200.5%0Av%20400%20368%20400%20272%200%200%2040%2020%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20288%20272%20288%20192%200%205000%0Ar%20400%20272%20400%20192%200%2010000%0Ad%20400%2096%20400%20192%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20288%20192%20288%2096%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20288%2096%20400%2096%200%0Aw%20288%20368%20400%20368%200%0Aw%20112%2096%20112%20208%200%0Aw%20112%20320%20112%20368%200%0Aw%20128%20368%20288%20368%200%0Aw%20128%20368%20112%20368%200%0Ag%20256%20368%20256%20400%200%0Av%20112%20320%20112%20208%200%200%2040%2030%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20400%2096%20480%2096%200%0Aw%20480%2096%20480%20112%200%0Aw%20400%20368%20480%20368%200%0Aw%20480%20368%20480%20352%200%0Ar%20208%2096%20288%2096%200%202500%0Ad%20112%2096%20208%2096%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20480%20112%20480%20352%200%205000%0A)